# How can I change data to json serializable

Tags: python, json, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm student learning flask rest web server.

I insert into mydatabase name : new.
If I use post mehtod, data insert into database table.
I want to load the data
There is a error. like this "TypeError: <**main**.User object at 0x104225cd0> is not JSON serializable "
How can I change my data json serializbale.

I'm sorry to I can't explain well. 
Thank you for reading my text. :)

```
app = Flask(__name__)


app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'mysql://root:12345@localhost/new'
db = SQLAlchemy(app)

class User(db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(80))
    email = db.Column(db.String(120))
    password = db.Column(db.String(120))

    def __init__(self, name, email, password):
        self.name = name
        self.email = email
        self.password = password

@app.route('/user',methods=['post'])
def create():

    user = User(request.json.get('name',''), request.json.get('email',''), request.json.get('password',''))
    db.session.add(user)
    db.session.commit()
    return 200

@app.route('/userlist', methods = ['GET'])
def index():
    users = User.query.all()
    return jsonify({'user' : User.query.all() })
```

Comment: paste you  complete error

Comment: Oh, Thank you for reponse. this is full error '''raise TypeError(repr(o) + " is not JSON serializable")
TypeError: <__main__.User object at 0x104226cd0> is not JSON serializable'''

Answer (score 0):

In general jsonify needs a CustomEncoder for custom objects such as your user. 
This is also true for the flask jsonify. Take a look at [their documentation for an example of this](http://flask.pocoo.org/snippets/119/).

I'd say a similar approach for your user class should work for you.